# Android Using GridView with OnScrollListener load 10 images

Tags: java, android, gridview

I'm building a gridview that contains alot of images likely around 1000+ pictures. To reduce the loading time for the gridview, I want to 10 load image 
tnx

GalleryActivity .java

```
    public class GalleryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private GridView gridView;
    private GridViewAdapter gridAdapter;
    ArrayList<String> f = new ArrayList<String>();// list of file paths
    File[] listFile;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_gallery);

        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        gridAdapter = new GridViewAdapter(this, R.layout.grid_item_layout, getData());
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);
        //gridView.setOnScrollChangeListener(new EndlessScrollListener());

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
                ImageItem item = (ImageItem) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                //Create intent
                Intent intent = new Intent(GalleryActivity.this, DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("title", R.string.text_by + item.getTitle());
                intent.putExtra("subtitle", R.string.text_by + item.getSubtitle());
                intent.putExtra("image", item.getAddress());

                //Start details activity
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        gridView.setOnItemLongClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(GalleryActivity.this, "333 " + position,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> getData() {
        final ArrayList<ImageItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
        getFromSdcard();
        for (int i = 0; i < f.size(); i++) {
            Bitmap bitmap = createThumbnailFromBitmap(f.get(i), 200, 200);
            Bitmap bitmapIcon = createThumbnailFromBitmap(f.get(i), 50, 50);
            imageItems.add(new ImageItem(bitmap,bitmapIcon,f.get(i),f.get(i),f.get(i)));
        }
        return imageItems;
    }
    public void getFromSdcard()
    {
        File file= new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"DCIM/Camera");
        if (file.isDirectory())
        {
            listFile = file.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length ; i++)
            {
                f.add(listFile[i].getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
    }
    private Bitmap createThumbnailFromBitmap(Bitmap source, int width, int height){
        //OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT- Constant used to indicate we should recycle the input
        return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(source, width, height, ThumbnailUtils.OPTIONS_RECYCLE_INPUT);
    }
    private Bitmap createThumbnailFromBitmap(String filePath, int width, int height){
        return ThumbnailUtils.extractThumbnail(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath), width, height);
    }
}
```

ImageItem.java

```
public class ImageItem {
    private Bitmap image;
    private Bitmap icon;
    private String title;
    private String subtitle;
    private String address;

    public ImageItem(Bitmap image,Bitmap icon, String title, String subtitle,String address) {
        super();
        this.image = image;
        this.icon = icon;
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
        this.address = address;
    }
    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }
    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }
    public Bitmap getIcon() {
        return icon;
    }
    public void setIcon(Bitmap icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
    }
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
    public String getSubtitle() {
        return subtitle;
    }
    public void setSubtitle(String subtitle) {
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

GridViewAdapter .java

```
public class GridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ImageItem> {

    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<ImageItem> data = new ArrayList<ImageItem>();

    public GridViewAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, ArrayList<ImageItem> data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.imageTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.text_date_card_mochgir);
            holder.subtitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.secondary_by_card_mochgir);
            holder.image = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.image_card_mochgir);
            holder.icon = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.icon_app_mochgir);
            row.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) row.getTag();
        }

        ImageItem item = data.get(position);
        holder.imageTitle.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.text_date) + item.getTitle());
        holder.subtitle.setText(getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.text_by) + item.getSubtitle());
        holder.image.setImageBitmap(item.getImage());
        holder.icon.setImageBitmap(item.getIcon());

        return row;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView imageTitle;
        TextView subtitle;
        ImageView image;
        ImageView icon;
    }
}
```

.....

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:columnWidth="200dp"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:verticalSpacing="4dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
    android:paddingLeft="4dp"
    android:paddingRight="4dp"
    android:paddingTop="4dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:contextClickable="true"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
    android:longClickable="true"/>
```

Comment: I can only see code. What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please visit the help page on [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and rework your question to include a minimal verifiable complete example with some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you use RecyclerView instead and you wont have to worry about the loading time cause recyclerview destroys item that is not in view and loads only what is in view making it fast and efficient.

To setup RecycerView, checkout this post:
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/getting-started-with-recyclerview-and-cardview-on-android--cms-23465
Hope this help,